# Code First - EntityType 'Compiler Results' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, codedom

Here is the full error:

> {"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nContentManager.CompilerResults: : EntityType 'CompilerResults' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCompilerResults: EntityType: EntitySet 'CompilerResults' is based on type 'CompilerResults' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}

This is such a strange error. First of all, I have no class called CompilerResults in that namespace (ContentManager.CompilerResults). Second of all, there is no "EntityType 'CompilerResults'". Here is the entity class I made called "ContextEntityPair":

```
[Table("context_entity_pair")]
public class ContextEntityPair
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column("context_name")]
    public string ContextName { get; set; }

    [Column("entity_compiler_results")]
    public CompilerResults EntityCompilerResults { get; set; }

    public ContextEntityPair(Guid id, string contextName, CompilerResults entityCompilerResults)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ContextName = contextName;
        this.EntityCompilerResults = entityCompilerResults;
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm doing everything I can to avoid a 'no key defined' error. I use the name "Id", I set it as a property, and I even give it a [Key] attribute. But for some reason it's not giving an error about Id not being a key. It says that 'CompilerResults' doesn't have a key which makes no sense. Here is the context I have for it:

```
namespace Laserfiche.BusinessEntities.ContentManager.ReadStore.EF
{
    public class EntityCompilerResultsContext : DbContext
    {
        public EntityCompilerResultsContext()
            : base("EFEntityCompilerResults")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntityCompilerResultsContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<ContextEntityPair> ContextEntityPairs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using a repository for some CRUD methods. Here is the beginning of it with the Insert method as an example method:

```
public class EntityContextRepository
{
    private readonly Type _entityType;
    private EntityCompilerResultsContext _db = new EntityCompilerResultsContext();

    public EntityContextRepository()
    {
        _entityType = typeof(ContextEntityPair);
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(ContextEntityPair pair)
    {
        try
        {
            Ensure.IsNotNull(pair, "pair");
            _db.ContextEntityPairs.Add(pair);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            DbEntityValidationExceptionHandle(dbEx);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the test code I'm running (there is some CodeDOM stuff -- just ignore it. The important part is where I define 'entityResults1' and everything from 'contextName' and below):

```
string entityName = "Curtain";

EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo entityField1 = new EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo("Color", typeof(string), RelationshipType.NoRelation);
EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo entityField2 = new EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo("Size", typeof(int), RelationshipType.NoRelation);

ICollection<EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo> listOfProps = new List<EntityGenerator.EntityFieldInfo> { entityField1, entityField2 };
EntityGenerator.CreateEntityClass(listOfProps, entityName);
CompilerResults entityResults1 = EntityGenerator.GetCompiledEntity(entityName);

GenericEntity entityInstance1 = (GenericEntity) EntityGenerator.CreateInstanceOfEntity(entityResults1, entityName);

SetObjectField(entityInstance1, "Color", "Green");
SetObjectField(entityInstance1, "Size", 20);

string contextName = "EFEntityTest_v1";
Guid testGuid1 = new Guid("00000000000000000000000000000001");

ContextEntityPair entityCompilerResultsPair = new ContextEntityPair(testGuid1, contextName, entityResults1);
EntityContextRepository contextEntityRepo = new EntityContextRepository();
contextEntityRepo.InsertAsync(entityCompilerResultsPair).Wait();
```

It breaks inside InsertAsync on the line:

```
_db.ContextEntityPairs.Add(pair);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 
`public CompilerResults EntityCompilerResults { get; set; }`
is not marked with `ComplexType` attribute, it's not a scalar property either, nor a reference. How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: Huh, I never thought that a CompilerResults object couldn't be inserted into a database. So is there a way to insert it? Or do I have to convert it to another type that the database can work with? I just tried using a [ComplexType] attribute above the class but it doesn't work (sorry I haven't worked with this attribute before so I'm not sure what else to do).

Comment: well that depends on how do you want to store it in database. You can read about complex-type properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx. Alternatively, you can have a separate table in database for `CompilerResults` and reference it via foreign key